# Is it important to retain tightness on deadlift eccentric?

Tags: deadlifts

I notice that till now whenever I do the deadlift eccentric, I let myself fall with the bar and don't focus too much on tightness. This ends to have an end position with rounded spine as I am not able to do knee extension to reduce hip height.

Is this okay to do? Or should I focus on remaining tight as I let it fall?

End state picture:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on your goals. Controlling the eccentric of the deadlift adds considerable fatigue to each set because it adds additional time under tension. If your main goal is strength pulling from the floor, that additional fatigue cost is probably better spent lifting heavier or doing additional sets. But if strength isn’t a primary concern, or you have more hypertrophy focused goals, you may stand to benefit from controlled eccentrics.

So it isn’t a question of which is “correct” or “better”, it just depends on what your goals and preferences are.

Comment: Being strong eccentrically reduces the risk of injuries, and increases your potential for concentric gains. At the very least, better to lower the bar under some control.